# Regex to find matches in a multi-line string after a certain phrase

Tags: java, regex

The content that I'm working on:

```
dontAccessMe:
abc
def

accessMe:
xyz
xyzt
foo
bar
```

I need to capture 3-letter words in the lines that are below the phrase `accessMe:`. Which are: `xyz foo bar`.

How do I go about achieving this?

I've tried `(?<=accessMe:)\s*(\w{3})` and it stops after the first matching word.

The language that I'm writing the regex in is Java 15.

Comment: Well, [`(?m)(?:\G(?!\A)\R+|accessMe:\R)(\w{3})$`](https://regex101.com/r/edQzcz/1)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew [this](https://regex101.com/r/nG5GLR/1) breaks when I have something that doesn't match below `accessMe:`.

Comment: Yeah, it is not a problem, you may solve it with `(?m)(?:\G(?!\A)(?:\R++(?!\w{3}$).*)*\R+|accessMe:\R)(\w{3})$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nG5GLR/2).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Regex here. Use the advantage that Java gives you. Assuming the input is a String, you can use [`Stream#dropWhile`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#dropWhile(java.util.function.Predicate)) method after you split the String by the new-line delimiter `\n`.

```
Arrays.stream(string.split("\\n"))                // split each line to a String
      .dropWhile(str -> !str.equals("accessMe:")) // ignore until "accessMe:" is reached
      .skip(1)                                    // skip "accessMe:" itself
      .forEach(System.out::println);              // print them out or collect
```

If the input is `List<String>` itself, you can call directly `.stream().dropWhile(..)` on it with no split.

> I need to capture 3-letter word

You can use an additional `filter` if you are really restricted to match only three-letter words. Place it after the `skip` method call:

```
      .filter(str -> str.length() == 3)
```